# Testing modal form using codeception

Tags: php, laravel, testing, codeception, acceptance-testing

How do I access a form inside a modal? Currently I have something like this, but I can't fill the form fields. It displays this error:

`[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidElementStateException] invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated`

```
$I->scrollTo($editButton);
$I->wait(4);
$I->click($editButton);
$I->waitForElement(".popUp-container");
$I->wait(3);
$I->waitForElement('#user-edition-form');
$I->fillField('//*[@id="edit-user-data"]/div[1]/div[2]/input', 'AAA');
```

Comment: According to the error, your modal is not poped up while you trying fill inputs inside it. Another approach is, try to trigger modal open via javascript `$I->executeJs('code to open modal rigth here')`. http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#executeJS

Comment: Sounds more like you're trying to fill a field that is disabled or hidden. Are you sure you are targeting the right element?

Comment: try to put a screenshot so you could debug if your modal is visible or not
`
$I->wait(3);
$I->makeScreenshot('checkModal');
$I->waitForElement('#user-edition-form');
`